# Combine 8 different shapefiles into 1 with combined attribute fields

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table, fields-attributes, combine

I am working on a project where I want to add the attribute fields of 7 different shapefiles into 1 base shapefile. Specifically, I have a parcel map of a city, and I want to append attribute fields onto each parcel (things like trash day, city councilor, etc). I was trying to do a Union of the Parcels and then each subsequent map one at a time, but I was wondering if there is a faster way to achieve this. I am using QGIS 3.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but did you try `join by location`?

Comment: I'm trying it now and I think it's exactly what I'm looking for. To try to explain better, I want to give each parcel the field attribute of an overlapping layer - ie, if a parcel is in District 2, add that field from layer "Council Districts" to the "Parcel" layer, and then replicate that with the other 5 layers.